# How can I filter an Observable onKeyUp?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, rxjs5, flatmap

How do I search / filter observable of type string array ?

For example , I have following observable

```
names$ = Observable.of(['Lenovo','Dell','Toshiba','Apple','Microsoft']);
```

Now I would like to filter this observable based on what user types in the input textbox.

So I have following code & I would like to return filtered observable based on user's searchTerm typed in the input box.

Please note that I am looking for client side solution. I have the data already on the clientside & for some reason I cannot send search term on server to filter the data. I also understand that in this example I can directly use filter on array itself but I want to do this through observable.

I also tried flatmap operator to flatten the array but still was not able to return the observable in the end which should be of type string array.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**App.component.html**

```
<!-- Textbox to receive user input -->
Search:<input type='text' [(ngModel)]='searchTerm' (keypress)='onkeypress($event.target.value)'>
<p>Search Term: {{searchTerm}}</p>
<hr>

<!-- Show search results here as ordered list -->
<ng-container *ngIf='(names$|async)?.length>0'>
    <ol>
        <li *ngFor='let name of names$|async'>
            {{name}}
        </li>
    </ol>
</ng-container>
```

**App.component.ts**

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    names$: Observable<string[]>;
    filteredNames$: Observable<string[]>;
    searchTerm: string;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.names$ = Observable.of(['Lenovo', 'Dell', 'Toshiba', 'Apple', 'Microsoft']);
    }

    // HOW TO IMPLEMENT THIS FUNCTION ??
    onkeypress(value) {
        console.log(value);
        this.names$ = this.names$.map(names => names.indexOf(value) > 0)
        // .filter(x=>{console.log(x.indexOf(value));return x.indexOf(value)>0})
        //     .subscribe(
        // (data)=>console.log(data),      (error)=>console.log('Error'+error),
        //       ()=>console.log('complete'));
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a small thing but you're listening for a keypress event and calling the function keyup. I'm not sure if you have the behavior you want here.

Comment: @Brendan Whiting Thanks for the pointing out the mistake. I fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few mistakes that you make here.

1. Why do you want to map the observable to `names.indexOf(value) > 0`? `.map()` literally transforms the observable, and you have just casted an observable of type `string` to type `boolean`.
2. If you want the list of `names` to change when the user are keying (onkeyup), why do you want to reassign the `this.names$` back to `this.names$` again? That will make your code work once aka work on the first key stroke only. You should have two variables, one for holding the values, the other to be bind to your `ngModel`.
3. If you want to use `async` pipe, there is no need for you to subscribe the observable in your typescript file.

In your `ngOnInit()`, create a variable to keep track of your names:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.data$ = Observable.of(['Lenovo', 'Dell', 'Toshiba', 'Apple', 'Microsoft']);
    this.names$ = this.data$;
}
```

Assuming you are using the `async` pipe, this should be your `onKeyUp` function:

```
onKeyUp(value) {
    this.names$ = this.data$
        .map(x => {
             return x.filter(y=>y.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase())>-1);
        })
}
```

Working Stackblits: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yeaer6

Comment: Thanks for your help. I understood all the comments you have mentioned & updated the code & fixed the keypress event as well. Here is the stackblitz link which exactly does what you have mentioned here.https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wtarys However I am expecting to see filtered list getting updated when I change the text but it is not doing it. Any idea why ?

Comment: @hp8888 my bad. Updated the code, and posted the stackblitz.

Comment: ,,,,Unfortunately It is still not working or it is not the behavior I want.I went to  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yeaer6 which is the link that should have working code. But when I type 'Del' in textbox it should show me Dell in the filtered list which it is not. I am sorry but I have to point this out. In similar way if I type 'Len' it should show Lenovo in the filtered list. You may have forgot to save the changes before you sent this link ?

Comment: @hp8888 my mistake! To get the behaviour you want, just make sure we compare the lowercases of allboth the inputs and the list. The link is updated.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking time to answer my question.. This is exactly I wanted. I should have figured out the case sensitive issue on my own.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
let value='Del'
 Rx.Observable.from(['Lenovo','Dell','Toshiba','Apple','Microsoft'])
 .filter(name=>name.indexOf(value)!==-1)
 .subscribe(console.log);
```

Comment: Hi Fan Cheung , Thanks for your time to answer my question. I tried the code you have here & it works perfectly fine. However I have one question. The moment I change the line Observable.from to Observable.of it stopped working. Can you please explain why following does not work (notice I called of method instead of from) ?`let value="Del"`
 `Rx.Observable.of(["Lenovo","Dell","Toshiba","Apple","Microsoft"])`
 `.filter(name=>name.indexOf(value)!==-1)`
 `.subscribe(console.log);`

Comment: .of will send you the whole list of array in one subscription, try .of(array).subscribe(console.log) and from(array).subscribe(console.log) and see the difference